# VBA print from excel without printing the comments

Tags: vba, excel

I want to print some of the sheets of a workbook without the extra pages of cell comments being listed.

Done quite a bit of research but have not worked out how to do it

The sub I am using is the following:

```
Sub PrintAllButtonEvent(control As IRibbonControl)
    Dim theWorksheet As Worksheet

   For Each theWorksheet In Sheets
      If Left(theWorksheet.Name, 1) <> "_" Then
         setPrintSize theWorksheet
         UpdateHeader theWorksheet
         theWorksheet.PrintOut
      End If
   Next theWorksheet
End Sub
```

The PrintOut method does not seem to have an option for suppressing the comments.

I can do it manually by doing the following:

1)File->Print->Page Setup->Sheet

2)Change the Comments drop down to (None) instead of At end of sheet

[image]

But I really need to be able to do it from code.

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.PrintComments = False
```

is the only way to force them off in 2016. `xlPrintNoComments` doesn't do it and actually keeps turning them back on. Possible Bug?

A pointer for printing options is to record a macro, set everything up how you want and then see what Excel gives you. In this case, it kept giving me `xlPrintNoComments` which as I just stated above, does NOT work.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my post zx. Not sure why it's down voted though because it is absolutely true and tested on multiple machines at my workplace. The best ranked answer here does not work in 2016.

Answer (score 3):

LOL writing the question gave me a clue and I solved it.

Its not a print option it is a page setup option.

```
Worksheet.PageSetup.PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
```

Tested and works

Comment: That's called *[rubber duck problem solving](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/)* - talk to your duck more often!

Comment: Just followed your link yes that is exactly what happened, and I its there for the next person who looks for it :)

Answer (score 2):

This approach also works - see last line

```
Sheets("CUSTOMER").Select
Range("CustomerSummaryPrintArea").Select
Range("CustomerSummaryPrintArea").Activate
Application.PrintCommunication = False

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = False`
```

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet.PageSetup.PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments` -> prints comments on the separate page

`Worksheet.PageSetup.PrintComments = false` -> does not print any comments, solves the problem